# pip: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'

Tags: pip

With `pip` on Ubuntu 14.04, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
from pip import main
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
vendored("cachecontrol")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
__import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 4, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 32, in vendored
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 47, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please install pyOpenSSL 16.2.0 and see if this is fixed?

Comment: What commands were you running with pip?

Answer (score 2):

## Use pip3

I had to switch over to using `pip3` to resolve this issue:

$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pyopenssl

Answer (score 1):

I found that [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46285505/1460422) helped. Basically, it says that you should do this:

```
rm -rf /home/<Your Username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL
sudo rm -rf usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Comment: works in WSL too.

Answer (score 0):

yeah pip errors until you fix it manually (chicken and egg mentioned)....find where the library is installed and manually delete it.

On my 16.04 installation I did this:

*cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

rm -rf OpenSSL*

Then pip worked correctly without the SSL error
*pip install pyopenssl*

Comment: Removing packages manually from `/usr/lib/python*/dist-packages`can be dangerous as it may break package updates from OpenSSL that provide the Python libraries.  You should refrain from manually removing files from package-manager-controlled directories when you can.

Comment: works in WSL too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo easy_install -U cryptography
```

Then install `pyopenssl` package:

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

I hope this works. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

You are missing pyOpenSSL package, or is outdated.

simply run

```
$ pip install pyopenssl
```

and update packages (may not be necessary).

Comment: .....but you can't do that, because `pip` is throwing the error! Classic chicken-and-egg problem here.....